# How to get data from two subscribers simultaneously

Tags: python, opencv, ros, calibration

I'm a beginner in ROS and i need a solution to the below case.

There is no data flow happening to the `self.img` inside `def get_MarkerPose(self)`. Why is that ??

Similarly, why is there no data flow to `self.robot_poses_msg = msg` inside `def get_ee_pose(self)` ??

I need the two functions `def get_MarkerPose(self)` and `def get_ee_pose(self)` to be retained in the code.

What is the better way to implement this ??

```
class HandEyeCalibration():
 
    def __init__(self):
        self.robot_pose = []
        self.image_pose = []
        self.img = Image()
        self.robot_poses_msg = Pose()
        self.bridge = CvBridge()

    rospy.init_node('Hand_Eye_calibration',anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('/rgb/image_raw',Image,self.image_callback)
    rospy.Subscriber('/direct_transform',Pose,self.position_callback)
 
    def image_callback(self,message):
        self.img = message
 
    def get_MarkerPose(self):
    # converting ros image to cv image and saving the poses
        cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(self.img,'mono8')
        temporay_pose = transform_from_image(cv_image)
        self.image_pose.append(temporary_pose)
 
    def position_callback(self,msg):
        self.robot_poses_msg = msg
 
    def get_ee_pose(self):
        print(self.robot_poses_msg)
        pose = tf.transformations.quaternion_matrix(np.array([self.robot_poses_msg.orientation.x,self.robot_poses_msg.orientation.y, self.robot_poses_msg.orientation.z, self.robot_poses_msg.orientation.w]))
        pose[0,3] = self.robot_poses_msg.position.x
        pose[1,3] = self.robot_poses_msg.position.y
        pose[2,3] = self.robot_poses_msg.position.z
        pose[3,:] = [0,0,0,1]
        self.robot_pose.append(pose) 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    rospy.loginfo('Robot will move in 5 sec, please stay away')
    calibration = HandEyeCalibration()
    rospy.spin()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are subscribing to two different topics to do calliberation. It seems like both are not syncronized so there is no data. you can use message_filter library to subscribe to both and than process.

an example can be:

```
rgb_image = message_filters.Subscriber('/rgb/image_raw',Image)
d_transform = message_filters.Subscriber('/direct_transform',Pose)
ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([rgb_image, d_transform], q_size, slop, allow_headerless=True)
ts.registerCallback(yourCallback)
```

You can use either `ApproximateTimeSynchronizer` or `TimeSynchronizer`. You can look for more details [here](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters)